# Create a uniuqe DataFrame that contains multiple dataframes grouped by email from diferent file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got  a  **users.csv**  file that hasa list of  emails. and also a  **report.csv**  file that  has  a bunch of  data  i want  to create  a  pdf  file, that  has only the data  that  match  the email from  **users.csv**

contents  of   **users.cvs**

```
users
victor.uriel@domain.com
urile.victor@domain.com
```

contents of  **report.csv**

```
Manager1      Location    User         Email                        Name          Notes 
Man           loc1        vicuri       victor.uriel@domain.com      XXKKYY        Blah Blah
Man           loc2        vicuri       victor.uriel@domain.com      XXKKYY        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        someUsr      non.existent@domain.com      XXYYkk        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        someUsr      non.existent@domain.com      XXYYkk        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        someUsr      non.existent@domain.com      XXYYkk        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        urivic       uriel.victor@domain.com      YYKKXX        Blah Blah
Man           loc2        urivic       uriel.victor@domain.com      YYKKXX        Blah Blah
Man           loc3        urivic       uriel.victor@domain.com      YYKKXX        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        someUsr      non.existent@domain.com      XXYYkk        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        someUsr      non.existent@domain.com      XXYYkk        Blah Blah
Man           loc1        someUsr      non.existent@domain.com      XXYYkk        Blah Blah
```

**what  i want to get:**

```
Location    User         Email                        Name          Notes 
loc1        vicuri       victor.uriel@domain.com      XXKKYY        Blah Blah blah
loc2        vicuri       victor.uriel@domain.com      XXKKYY        Blah Blah blah
loc1        urivic       uriel.victor@domain.com      YYKKXX        Blah Blah blah
loc2        urivic       uriel.victor@domain.com      YYKKXX        Blah Blah blah
loc3        urivic       uriel.victor@domain.com      YYKKXX        Blah Blah blah
```

im currently  able to iterate  over  my  **users.csv** file  and   create   multiple  dataframe.  and  i would be able to create  multiple  PDF  files  with  each individual  dataframe  data

but  i want  to have a  big dataframe   and  only generate one PDF file

I don't  know how  to  better  explain   and  hope  examples  makes  sense

My code:

```
import pandas as  pd
from fpdf import FPDF
import csv


def output_df_to_pdf(df,mwc):
    pdf_w= 420
    table_cell_width = 25
    table_cell_height = 8
    path= 'reports\\'
    

    loc_w = mwc['Location_w'] 
    use_w = mwc['user_w'] 
    ema_w = mwc['email_w'] 
    nam_w = mwc['name_w']
    not_w = mwc['notes_w']

    pdf = FPDF('L','mm','A3')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 20)
    # A cell is a rectangular area, possibly framed, which contains some text
    # Set the width and height of cell
    pdf.cell(20,10,'Report')
    pdf.image('..\common\Logo.jpg',x= 420 - 100, y = 13, w =80, h=table_cell_height+5)
    pdf.ln(20)
    # Select a font as Arial, bold, 8
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 8)
    pdf.set_fill_color(76,104,162)
    pdf.set_draw_color(224,224,224)
    pdf.set_text_color(255,255,255)

    # Creates Header  with main DF  width 
    cols = df.columns
    col_vals = {}
    for col in cols:
        col_vals[col] = col

    # Set  heade col with  correct  with 

    pdf.cell(loc_w +10, table_cell_height, col_vals['Title'], align='L', border=1, fill=1)
    pdf.cell(use_w +10, table_cell_height, col_vals['User'], align='L', border=1, fill=1)
    pdf.cell(ema_w +17, table_cell_height, col_vals['Email'], align='L', border=1, fill=1)
    pdf.cell(nam_w +10, table_cell_height, col_vals['Name'], align='L', border=1, fill=1)
    pdf.cell(not_w - 85, table_cell_height, col_vals['Notes'], align='L', border=1, fill=1)

    pdf.ln(table_cell_height)
    pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 6)

    for row in df.itertuples():
        val = {}
        for coli in cols:
            value = str(getattr(row, coli))
            val[coli]= value

        pdf.set_text_color(0,0,0)
        pdf.set_draw_color(224,224,224)
        # pdf.multi_cell(not_w - 80, table_cell_height, val['Notes'], align='L', border=1)

        if len(val['Notes']) > 230:

            pdf.cell(loc_w +10, table_cell_height *2, val['Title'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(use_w +10, table_cell_height *2, val['User'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(ema_w +17, table_cell_height *2, val['Email'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(nam_w +10, table_cell_height *2, val['Name'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.multi_cell(not_w - 85,table_cell_height,val['Notes'],align='L', border=1)
            
        else:

            pdf.cell(loc_w +10, table_cell_height, val['Title'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(use_w +10, table_cell_height, val['User'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(ema_w +17, table_cell_height, val['Email'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(nam_w +10, table_cell_height, val['Name'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.cell(not_w - 85, table_cell_height, val['Notes'], align='L', border=1)
            pdf.ln(table_cell_height)

    pdf.output(path + '2022 Awesome Report.pdf', 'F')






#start of program 
mails_df = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
mlist = mails_df['Email'].dropna().unique()
report_df = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
mdata = report_df


# get  max length  of  column  
mwc = { 
    'Location_w' : report_df['Location'].str.len().max(),
    'user_w' : report_df['User'].str.len().max(),
    'email_w' : report_df['Email'].str.len().max(),
    'name_w' : report_df['Name'].str.len().max(),
    'notes_w' : report_df['Notes'].str.len().max()
}


for data in mlist:
    res = mdata.loc[mdata['Email'].str.lower() == data].dropna()
    if(res.size > 0):
        df = res.drop('Manager1', axis=1)




output_df_to_pdf(df, mwc)
```

Answer (score 0):

just get the row containing the email addresses in the users.csv file. Can you try this:

```
report_v2 = report[report['Email'].isin(users['users'])]
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.